# logging for nginx controller in datadog

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, datadog

can someone help me with correct docs or blogs to set up up logging for nginx controller in datadog.
Currently nginx and datadog both are running on containers.

please what is the best way to do it, i am trying this first time